# [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

When we go from a view to another view with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` what's the first thing that run?(means which function or line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-viewWillDisappear` in the view controller of the modal view.

If you are aiming at the first thing not in the modal view, it is `-viewWillAppear` in the view controller of the previously underlying view.

Answer (score 1):

You can put some NSLog inside some methods like viewWillAppear:, viewDidAppear:, viewWillDisappear:, viewDidDisappear: ,and the method which calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO.